# How to get this Jquery data as an array?

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax

I have populated this data(as you will see in next image),the user inters some numbers, when the user hits Add to Cart(I use jQuery/Ajax),I need to get that data as an array somehow, but I can't get the perfect way. Actualy what you see in image is a product that has come colors, and comes in different sizes, but there are actualy more products, added one by one,becouse every product has his add to cart button.

[image]

Html Code:

```
<input type="text" data-colorID="1" data-galonID="5"  data-attribute="Clear" class="form-control ion Clear" name="barrel" aria-describedby="sizing-addon3">
```

Jquery Code, on Add to Cart button click:

```
 var barrel = [];
 $('input[name^=barrel]').each(function(){
    var attribute = $(this).data('attribute');
    barrel.push($(this).val());
});
```

But somehow I only get `Uncaught TypeError: barrel.push is not a function`, and when I use `barrel[attribute] = $(this).val();` I get `Object {Clear: "", Orange: "", Purple: ""}` , when I console.log it.

I want my array to look like this:

```
ProductID1->
colorID1->
    [key=GalonID]->input1 value
    [key=GalonID]->input2 value
    [key=GalonID]->input3 value
    [key=GalonID]->input4 value
colorID2->
    [key=GalonID]->input1 value
    [key=GalonID]->input2 value
    [key=GalonID]->input3 value
    [key=GalonID]->input4 value
colorID3->
    [key=GalonID]->input1 value
    [key=GalonID]->input2 value
    [key=GalonID]->input3 value
    [key=GalonID]->input4 value
```

Please Help, thanks!

Comment: please show enough relevant html to be able to see where `colorID` and `GalonID` come from

Comment: the easiest way is: data-colorID and data-galonID, using data attributes.

Comment: Sure... but you need to show where you set those

Comment: Where do you define `barrel`?  Is it an array .....like `var barrel =[]`?

Comment: @ charlietfl-changed the input to add the data.  @ DelightedD0D - var barrel =[] is above that jQuery code

Comment: No, I mean this line  `barrel.push($(this).val());` ....you have not defined `barrel` as an array, at least not in what you are showing us

Comment: Also, does it have to be an array, or can it be an object? In my opinion, you'd be better served making an object, sending it as json to the server, where your php can read it as an associative array

Comment: add the barrel array. actualy doesn't mather what it is. I just need that data. I am too tired to think propperly now :) but still need abit of help.

Comment: I'm sure You're getting the warning `Uncaught TypeError: barrel.push is not a function` **because `barrel` in not an array**, give me a few minutes and I'll work you up an example of how I would do it instead

Comment: how to fix it please? what I need to change/add?

Comment: see my edit to the comment above

Comment: here is a working fiddle:http://fiddle.jshell.net/suchit/2roqg19L/

Comment: @Suchit-I am pass this stage.  @ DelightedD0D - waiting for that example pelase

Comment: @Suchit your example does not work because you have not addressed the issue with the OP's data attributes having uppercase letter ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

**note that I have changed your data attribute to use all lower case letters.**
[Working example](http://dodsoftware.com/sotests/data_via_ajax_test/index.php)

```js
    $('#test').click(function () {
        var data = [];
        $('[data-color-id]').each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            var colorID = $this.data('color-id');
            var galonID = $this.data('galon-id');
            var attribute = $this.data('attribute');
            var count = $this.val();
            var name = $this.attr('name');
            // do any needed validation here
            data.push({
                colorID: encodeURIComponent(colorID),
                galonID: encodeURIComponent(galonID),
                count: encodeURIComponent(count),
                attribute: encodeURIComponent(attribute),
                name: name
            });
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "index.php",
            data: {
                data: data
            },
            success: function (response) {
                $('#result').html(response);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                alert(err.Message);
            }
        });

    });
```

```html
<input type="text" data-color-id="1" data-galon-id="5" data-attribute="Clear" class="form-control ion Clear" name="barrel" aria-describedby="sizing-addon3">
<input type="text" data-color-id="1" data-galon-id="5" data-attribute="Clear" class="form-control ion Clear" name="barrel" aria-describedby="sizing-addon3">
<input type="text" data-color-id="1" data-galon-id="5" data-attribute="Clear" class="form-control ion Clear" name="barrel" aria-describedby="sizing-addon3">
<input type="text" data-color-id="1" data-galon-id="5" data-attribute="Clear" class="form-control ion Clear" name="barrel" aria-describedby="sizing-addon3">
<input type="text" data-color-id="1" data-galon-id="5" data-attribute="Clear" class="form-control ion Clear" name="barrel" aria-describedby="sizing-addon3">
<button id="test"></button>
```

Then, on the php page, do something like:

```
if(isset($_POST["data"])){
    foreach($_POST['data'] as $item)
    {
        echo '<h4>Order Item</h4>';
        echo 'colorID =' .$item['colorID'].'<br>';
        echo 'galonID =' .$item['galonID'].'<br>';
        echo 'attribute =' .$item['attribute'].'<br>';
        echo 'count =' .$item['count'].'<br>';
        echo 'name =' .$item['name'].'<br>';
    }
    exit;
}
```